# Populate a ListView with Keysets

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

I am new to Android and Java but I have been trying to do this for a while now and have some ideas to how this may work, but I don't know how to put it in code.

I have two Activities, one that is a Log and one that creates a new log.   Basically, when a user makes a new log and saves it, it is saved as a keyset with the key being the Log Name.

I then want to take the newly created Log entry and add it to my list on another Activity.

I can only seem to populate the first item in the list with all the KeySets instead of them being listed one by one by adding as a new item.

The code I need is just to populate each item in the ListView as one of the Keys in the KeySets and when the user clicks it loads the values.

The code I have from ActivityLog:

```
public void loadLog (View view){

SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
    String myString = userInfo.getAll().keySet().toString();
    String[] values = new String[] { myString
    };


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1 );


    Map<String, ?> allEntries = userInfo.getAll();
    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {

        Log.d("map values", entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue().toString());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }}
```

Code for ActivityNewLog:

```
public void saveLog (View view){


    EditText Date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editDate);
    EditText Name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
    EditText Cal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editCal);
    EditText STime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editSTime);
    EditText ETime = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editETime);
    EditText Entry = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editEntry);

    try {
        SharedPreferences userInfo = getSharedPreferences("userData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = userInfo.edit();
        Set<String> LogSet = new HashSet<String>();

        LogSet.add(Date.getText().toString());
        LogSet.add(Name.getText().toString());
        LogSet.add(Cal.getText().toString());
        LogSet.add(STime.getText().toString());
        LogSet.add(ETime.getText().toString());
        editor.putStringSet( Entry.getText().toString(), LogSet);
        editor.commit();
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "User data saved!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();


    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        // insert your own error message here
    }


}
```

I would appreciate any help or advice to improve this code.

Comment: Why do you need a `Set` instead of a `List`?

Comment: i used sets because each set is holding values of the new log screen, such as, date,name,time etc. and i need to access these later on and i just assumed a set was the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use a SQLite database instead, but here you put a key into the `SharedPreferences` / `HashMap`.

```
editor.putStringSet( Entry.getText().toString(), LogSet);
```

Now, you have to get that value back out...

```
Map<String, ?> allEntries = userInfo.getAll();
Set<String> entry = allEntries.get("<some value here>"); // <-- Whatever you put in
```

And when you have that, you can loop over them to add to the adapter.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.activity_list_item, android.R.id.text1 );
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

for (String s : entry) {
    adapter.add(s);
}
```

Comment: minutes after posting this i used a method very similar to this but structured in a different way and it works so Thank you very much as this is perfect